# JavaScript - how to use Setters and Getters in to create a listener

Tags: javascript, listener, getter-setter

**Before this gets marked as a duplicate**: I have read posts all day about this so I know there are tons of *similar* questions on SO but none that I've seen so far go into the details that I need to understand.

Having said that, there are no good commented examples of how the process works. Could someone answer the following question with well a well-commented example so I could finally understand this ability?

I have a function that I want to call in one file but I need to make sure that another event in another file has already happened before I call it. These files have no connection (one is an angular 2 TypeScript file that starts the app and the other is a JS file that manages a hopscotch tour). I understand that I will need to use a global variable and I believe that the best solution I've read is going to involve using setters and getters. **All** examples I've seen of this seem to assume that it's just intuitive and leave out the part where I get to understand how it's working. Maybe it is intuitive but I'm not making the leap yet.

Global variable in TypeScript file:

```
global_variable = false;
```

Function I want to call in JavaScript file based on the listener:

```
function call_if_other_function_finishes() {
   if (global_variable === true) { // I have the global already created
       // run hopscotch tour
   }
} // how do I turn this into a listener?
```

The function I need to have finished first in TypeScript file:

```
function someFunction() {
    // run its code   
    GlobalFile.global_variable = true; // Should trigger the listener.
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use a promise...

Comment: No, don't use setter/getters that make everything confusing. Just make the global variable a callback function that you can call.

Comment: I understand and appreciate giving me alternate suggestions. But whether or not I end up using the setter/getter approach I still want to understand it.

Comment: Use `GlobalFile = {set global_variable(val) { if (val) /* run hopscotch tour */ }}` then. Notice that setters/getters work with properties only, not with variables

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to just define the function as you do in your example and then run it when you need it:

```
function someFunction() {
  // run its code
  call_if_other_function_finishes() // it's globally defined anyway
}
```